# Show $(a, b], (-\infty, a]$, and $(b, \infty)$ are fields, but not sigma fields

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Show that all finite unions of intervals in R of the form $(a, b], (-\infty, a]$, and $(b, \infty)$ are not $\sigma$-field.

I think it's a simple question but I have just started studying probability theory on my own so I might find it a little bit difficult in understanding the topics.

**What I think:** So for the above interval if we take the unions of it we get the entire Real line. And the set of all-natural numbers is infinite and its complement is infinite so it does not belong to this class since we are taking finite unions. But I am not sure if my logic is correct or not.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Non-finiteness of the set of natural numbers and its complement does not contradict the fact that the family is  sigma field.

But $\bigcup_n (2n,2n+1]$ is a countbale union of intervals each of which belongs to your family, but this union does not belong to the family. Hence, your family is not a sigma field.